# How to revert back to older elementary package?

Tags: epiphany, package

Epiphany 3.8.10 has way too many bugs to be usable. 3.8.5 has it's share of issues as well, but is more usable overall. Anyone know how to revert back to 3.8.5? I've tried with Synaptic but it's not available in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Use `apt-get install «pkg»=«version»`.
That should downgrade your application.

You'll also need to hold the package from updates with `sudo apt-mark hold package_name`

Comment: It said it can't find the package. They must have yanked it from repositories :/

Comment: :/ maybe you can download it somewhere in the internet

Comment: I did find a .deb file on Launchpad and was able to download from there. I haven't though been able to lock that version. I attempted to with Synaptic and through the command line, but I'm still receiving update notifications through the App Center. Oh well.

Comment: Install .deb package (uninstall installed version before) and without updating use hold command. It should work

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did. Removed the package through App Center. Downloaded and installed the .deb for epiphany-browser and the data package as well. Installed both via gdebi then ran the hold command. Didn't work, so I went into Synaptic and did Lock Version. Again did not work. As polished as many of the eOS apps are, they have always had issues with web browsers :/

Comment: Then sorry, I can't help you here. I do everything in terminal and from my short experience with App Center, I think that it may not work properly (e.g. I was not able to install anything via App Center - only in terminal; The same with Synaptic- probably I'm not smart enough to use these type of software)